# Hibernate Search - indexed ManyToOne relation

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two indexed entities

```
@Entity @Indexed
public class AEntity implements {

    @Id
    private String externalId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "externalId")
    private Set<BEntity> bEntities;
    
}

@Entity @Indexed
public class BEntity {

    @JsonIgnore @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
    @JoinColumn(name = "externalId", updatable = false)
    private AEntity aEntity;
    
}
```

Now when I search into BEntity like this:

```
private QueryBuilder getQuery() {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = getFullTextEntityManager();
    return fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(BEntity.class).get();
}
    
Query query = getQuery().bool()
                .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("aEntity.externalId").matching(externalId).createQuery())
                .createQuery();
```

I have the below error:

> Unable to find field aEntity.externalId in BEntity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID field is not included by `@IndexedEmbedded` by default.

There are limitations to what you can do with the document ID field, so personally I'd recommend defining an actual field, separate from the document ID. That way you can safely make it sortable, normalized, or whatever you want:

```
@Entity @Indexed
public class AEntity implements {

    @Id
    @DocumentId(name = "docId") // CHANGE HERE
    @Field // CHANGE HERE
    private String externalId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "externalId")
    private Set<BEntity> bEntities;
    
}

@Entity @Indexed
public class BEntity {

    @JsonIgnore @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
    @JoinColumn(name = "externalId", updatable = false)
    private AEntity aEntity;
    
}
```

But if you really want to use the document ID field, you can just use `@IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)`:

```
@Entity @Indexed
public class AEntity implements {

    @Id
    private String externalId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "externalId")
    private Set<BEntity> bEntities;
    
}

@Entity @Indexed
public class BEntity {

    @JsonIgnore @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1, includeEmbeddedObjectId = true) // CHANGE HERE
    @JoinColumn(name = "externalId", updatable = false)
    private AEntity aEntity;
    
}
```

Don't forget to reindex your data after changing the annotations.